# Cursor in UITextView on smaller iPhone's not centered until 1st word pressed

Tags: ios, cursor, uitextview

The cursor is initially off frame when it initially has the focus, but then after the first character is typed it is centered.  This happens on the smaller iPhones (5s, SE).  See screenshots:

**Initial Focus:**

[image]

**After typing 1 character it centers**

[image]

Comment: Please explain bit brifly

Comment: ur using programmatically textview or Storyborad ??? if your using Storyboard goto change position cursor

Comment: I am using storyboard, It's centered though for the iPhone 6

Comment: Use autolayout , works fine